# Replace second instance of duplicate values with 0

Tags: sql-server

I have data records which again based on some tables and calculation and my output looks like

```
ItemCode    LineTotalSum1   ShippingExpenseCode TotalShippingAmt
Item_O      9140.5           10                 13.24
Item_O      9140.5           13                 6.62
Item_O      9140.5           6                  744
Item_P      9099             10 <- 0 here       13.24
Item_P      9099             6  <- 0 here       744
```

Now I want to replace second duplicate value on column `ShippingExpenseCode` with 0, What exactly I should write on SQL script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We're glad to have you :)  Please edit your question to include the tables and calculations - links can go dead, and I have no intention of clicking anything.  It would also be helpful to post the SQL script you currently have.

Comment: @AHiggins 1 rep users can't post images as far as I know so have edited it in

Comment: Duplicate according to which column(s)?

Comment: That looks like Excel? Please extend the question with much more detail otherwise it will quickly get down voted and closed. You can delete the question and make edits and then un-delete it when you're finished to avoid it being closed before you're finished with your edits.

Comment: @TimSchmelter duplicates as in they already appear in that column. I suppose the ExpenseCode cannot be repeated?!

Comment: whats the datatype of the column 'ShippingExpenseCode'?

Answer (score 1):

If duplicates are determined by the first three columns `CardCode`,`DocPostingDate` and `ItemCode`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT CNT = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CardCode, DocPostingDate, ItemCode), *
    FROM dbo.TableName t
)
UPDATE CTE SET ShippingExpenseCode = 0
WHERE CNT > 1
```

Comment: The image was more useful to your answer I guess. OP edited image out and added data instead without those column. May be worth a rollback?

Comment: @Tanner: yes, my answer is related to the image which is now removed. I don't want to change the answer again, i hope OP will get the point.

Comment: Hi @Tim it is not working, it replace first instance instead of second instance

Comment: @gajar: actually it updates all rows which have these duplicate fields. The question was not that clear. What do you want to change and what should keep its value?

Comment: @Tim If duplicate value comes on same column then replace all instance except very first,It is shown on table on question right now

Answer (score 0):

I got script to replace all second or greater instance with 0 using following script.

```
Update T1 Set T1.TotalShippingAmt = 0,TotalShippingVAT = 0
from dbo.Table
where Row <> (Select MIN(Row) from dbo.Table T2 
    where    
        T2.ShippingExpenseCode = T1.ShippingExpenseCode And 
        T2.CardCode = T1.CardCode And T2.DocPostingDate = T1.DocPostingDate)
```